# Wordpress *custom* Session Value usage?

Tags: wordpress, session

How can i use my own (custom) session value inside wordpress?
For example: `$_SESSION['myname']="4lvin"`

I've already inserted `session_start()` at all page i need as following.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['myname'] = "4lvin";
?>
```

But not working.
Just working on the self page.
It is NOT call-able from another pages (using same logic).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add following lines at the top of `wp-config.php`

```
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}
```

Then add following line at the top of `header.php`

```
session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you start the session? `session_start()` must be called on every page that you want to use sessions. [See the documentation for examples](http://us.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).

Comment: yes i've tried `session_start()` at all page i need. But not working. :(